# How to coerce AWK to evaluate string as math expression?

Tags: math, awk, evaluate

Is there a way to evaluate a string as a math expression in awk?

```
balter@spectre3:~$ echo "sin(0.3) 0.3" | awk '{print $1,sin($2)}'
sin(0.3) 0.29552
```

I would like to know a way to also have the first input evaluated to 0.29552.

Comment: How about using this `echo "sin(0.3) 0.3" | awk '{match($1,/\(.*\)/);print sin(substr($1,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)),sin($2)}'` :)  I know you want to pass it as a MATH expression(which I am not aware as of now, looking  to documentations), thought a funny way to play around with this one.

Comment: Well, there is the extended version of `calc3` awk script by Kenny McCormack and Alan Linton floating around the internets, here is one link: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.awk/C4SbutsY1JA The original `calc3` only supported basic operations but the linked one seems to handle sin and such.

Comment: `echo "sin(0.3)" | awk -f calc3.awk` produces `sin(0.3) =         0.29552`

Comment: ````echo "sin(0.3) 0.3" | perl -ne ' /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ and print eval($1), " ", $2 '```` would also work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple one liner!

```
math(){ awk "BEGIN{printf $1}"; }
```

Examples of use:

```
math 1+1
```

Yields "2"

```
math 'sqrt(25)'
```

Yeilds "5"

```
x=100; y=5; math "sqrt($x) + $y"
```

Yeilds "15"

Answer (score 6):

You can just create your own eval function which calls awk again to execute whatever command you want it to:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ print eval($1), sin($2) }

function eval(str,      cmd,line,ret) {
    cmd = "awk \047BEGIN{print " str "; exit}\047"
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        ret = line
    }
    close(cmd)
    return ret
}

$ echo 'sin(0.3) 0.3' | awk -f tst.awk
0.29552 0.29552

$ echo '4*7 0.3' | awk -f tst.awk
28 0.29552

$ echo 'tolower("FOO") 0.3' | awk -f tst.awk
foo 0.29552
```

Answer (score 4):

awk lacks an `eval(...)` function.  This means that you cannot do string to code translation based on input after the awk program initializes.  Ok, perhaps it could be done, but not without writing your own parsing and evaluation engine in awk.

I would recommend using `bc` for this effort, like

```
[edwbuck@phoenix ~]$ echo "s(0.3)" | bc -l
.29552020666133957510
```

Note that this would require `sin` to be shortened to `s` as that's the `bc` sine operation.

Comment: Why isn't there a sane command line math library for linux? My current solution is `m(){ python -c "import math; print($1);}`. I could use perl as well. My previous boss saw this and told me I had just built the worlds most expensive calculator.

Comment: @abalter I was thinking that `bc` was for `basic calculator` and satisfied the "sane command line math" need; but, there is no shortage of ways to do Math in Linux.  I agree that `s(..)` and `c(...)` are odd ways of writing `sin` and `cos`, it's a shame they didn't opt for `sin(...)` and `cos()`.  Also, one could almost use bash's `echo $(($expr))` approach, except that it doesn't support trig.

Comment: @EdwinBuck Interestingly POSIX limits function and variable names in bc to be a single letter. (While multi letter implementations are available)

Comment: @abalter wrt `Why isn't there a sane command line math library for linux?` - because that's not what a shell is for. A shell is an environment from which to call tools and has a small language to help sequence those calls. It's not intended/designed to be a full featured programming language and if you're trying to use it as such then you're missing the point.

Answer (score 2):

With gawk version 4.1.2 :

```
echo "sin(0.3) 0.3" | awk '{split($1,a,/[()]/);f=a[1];print @f(a[2]),sin($2)}'
```

It's ok with `tolower(FOO)` too.

Comment: Good idea for function calls that take single numeric or string arguments (you just couldn't use it with `4*7` or `index("abc","b")` or `sin(0.1+0.2)` for example). btw `[(]|[)]` = `[()]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl as it has eval() function.

```
$  echo "sin(0.3)" | perl -ne ' print eval '
0.29552020666134
$
```

For the given input,

```
$ echo "sin(0.3) 0.3" | perl -ne ' /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ and print eval($1), " ", $2 '
0.29552020666134 0.3
$
```