# Variable operator for numerical comparison in awk

Tags: awk

Can awk use variable operators for numerical comparison? The following code works with a hard coded operator, but not with a variable operator:

```
awk -v o="$operator" -v c="$comparison" '$1 o c'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that cannot work. Awk's `-v` option defines actual Awk variables, and not token-level macro substitutions.

It doesn't work for the same reason that this doesn't work:

```
awk 'BEGIN { o = "+"; print 2 o 2 }'  # hoping for 2 + 2
```

Awk is different from the POSIX shell and similar languages; it doesn't evaluate variables by means of textual substitution.

Since you're calling Awk from a shell command line, you can use the shell's substitution to generate the Awk syntax, thereby obtaining that effect:

```
awk -v c="$comparison" "\$1 $operator c"
```

We now need a backslash on the `$1` because we switched to double quotes, inside of which `$1` is now recognized by the shell itself.

Comment: at this point there is no need for the variable either, move it in the quotes as well.

Comment: @karakfa Without knowing the exact content of `comparison`, we cannot make that call.  Consider `awk -v c='a"b' 'BEGIN { print c }'`.  If we interpolate `a"b` into the body of the Awk script in place of `c`, that will generate a syntax error, even if we put it in quotes. On the other hand `$operator` is probably a valid Awk operator token, by design.  The `-v` mechanism exists for a reason; it is more robust than interpolating text into the Awk syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to the one proposed by [Kaz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54431429/8344060) would be to define your own mapping function which takes the two variables as argument and the corresponding operator string `o`:

```
awk -v o="$operator" -v c="$comparison" '
      function operator(arg1, arg2, op) {
          if (op == "==") return arg1 == arg2
          if (op == "!=") return arg1 != arg2
          if (op == "<") return arg1 < arg2 
          if (op == ">") return arg1 > arg2
          if (op == "<=") return arg1 <= arg2 
          if (op == ">=") return arg1 >= arg2 
      }
    { print operator($1,c,o) }'
```

This way you can also define your own operators.

Comment: I like this, it allows `if (operator(a,op,b) { <commands> }` - very flexible for selecting with different criteria on each field.

Answer (score 0):

No but you have a couple of options, the simplest being to let the shell expand one of the variables to become part of the awk script before awk runs on it:

```
$ operator='>'; comparison='3'
$ echo 5 | awk -v c="$comparison" '$1 '"$operator"' c'
5
```

Otherwise you can write your own `eval`-style function, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
cmp($1,o,c)

function cmp(x,y,z,      cmd,line,ret) {
    cmd = "awk \047BEGIN{print (" x " " y " " z ")}\047"
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        ret = line
    }
    close(cmd)
    return ret
}

$ echo 5 | awk -v c="$comparison" -v o="$operator" -f tst.awk
5
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54161251/1745001. The latter would work even if your awk program was saved in a file while the former would not. If you want to mix a library of functions with command line scripts then here's one way with GNU awk for `-i`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
function cmp(x,y,z,      cmd,line,ret) {
    cmd = "awk \047BEGIN{print (" x " " y " " z ")}\047"
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ) {
        ret = line
    }
    close(cmd)
    return ret
}

$ awk -v c="$comparison" -v o="$operator" -i tst.awk 'cmp($1,o,c)'
5
```