# Arithmetic replacement in a text file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file like this:

```
id=1+5
id=1+9
id=25100+10
xyz=1+
abc=123456
conf_string=LMN,J,IP,25100+1,0,3,1
```

I would like to replace instances of x+y to the value of (x+y). That is 1+5 is replaced by 6, 25100+1 is replaced by 25001 and so on.

I was trying this with gawk by matching with a regex like `/[:digit:]++[+digit:]+/`
Using the following I could replace some of the instances.

```
gawk 'BEGIN {FS = "[=+,]"} ; /[:digit:]++[+digit:]+/ {print $1 "=" ($2 + $3)} ! /[:digit:]++[+digit:]+/ {print $0}' /tmp/1.txt
```

```
id=6
id=10
id=25110
xyz=1+
abc=123456
conf_string=LMN,J,IP,25100+1,0,3,1
```

I am unsure of how to match and replace (25100+1) in the above example. Ideally, I would like to extract all instances of `<number> + <number>` and replace it with the sum. It will always be a sum of two numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `GNU awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{r = @/([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/}
       { while(match($0, r, m)) sub(r, m[1] + m[2]) } 1' ip.txt
id=6
id=10
id=25110
xyz=1+
abc=123456
conf_string=LMN,J,IP,25101,0,3,1
```

- `r=@/([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/` save the regex in a variable, `[0-9]` will match all digits
- `match($0, r, m)` will be true if the regex matches, portion matched will be available in `m` array
- `m[1] + m[2]` sum the two numbers
- For older versions, use `awk '{while(match($0, /([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/, m)) sub(/([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/, m[1] + m[2]) } 1' ip.txt` as saving regex in a variable is not supported

**Note**

- `[:digit:]` should be used inside a character class `[[:digit:]]`
- `++` should be `+\+` as you intend the second one to match `+` literally

See also: [How to coerce AWK to evaluate string as math expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54156761/how-to-coerce-awk-to-evaluate-string-as-math-expression)

With `perl` you can simply use `e` flag to evaluate the replacement as code

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+)\+(\d+)/$1+$2/ge' ip.txt
# or    
perl -pe 's/\d+\+\d+/$&/gee' ip.txt
```

Comment: Very nice and concise! +1

Comment: @Sundeep I get a syntax error while running the command you sent. I am not so well versed in awk syntax, so could not easily resolve the error. ``` gawk 'BEGIN{r = @/([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/}
       { while(match($0, r, m)) sub(r, m[1] + m[2]) } 1' 3.txt
gawk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN{r = @/([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/}
gawk: cmd. line:1:            ^ syntax error
```

Comment: @javed could be because of version differences, I tested it on `gawk version 5.1.0` ... does `awk '{while(match($0, /([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/, m)) sub(/([0-9]+)\+([0-9]+)/, m[1] + m[2]) } 1'` work?

Comment: Yes, the awk command worked. I have 'GNU Awk 4.1.4', perhaps that is why the error came. Thank you for the updated command.

Comment: I have accepted this solution, because it worked for me the earliest. Other solutions from @RavinderSingh13 & agc also worked out equally well. Thank you everyone for helping me out.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk`, with shown samples. This solution will take care of conditions in case any 2nd field is starting with `+` or ending with `+` , like 4th line in output. Edited code tested on following link https://ideone.com/x2EQ0P

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="="
}
{
  num=split($2,array1,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    num1=split(array1[i],array2,"+")
      for(k=1;k<=num1;k++){
        if(num1==1){array1[i]=array2[k] }
        if(array2[k]~/^[0-9]+$/){
           val+=array2[k]
           array1[i]=(array2[1]!=""?"":"+") val (array2[num1]!=""?"":"+")
        }
     }
     val=""
  }
  for(o=1;o<=num;o++){
    value=(value?value ",":"")array1[o]
  }
  $2=value
  value=""
}
1
' Input_file
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                             ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                            ##Starting BEGIN section of this code from here.
  FS=OFS="="                                      ##Setting field separator nd output field separator as = here.
}
{
  num=split($2,array1,",")                        ##Splitting 2nd field here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                            ##Running for loop till value of num here.
    num1=split(array1[i],array2,"+")              ##Splitting 2nd field further to array2 with delimiter + here.
      for(k=1;k<=num1;k++){                       ##Running for loop to all fields wchih are separated by + here.
        val+=array2[k]                            ##Creating val which keeps on adding value of array2 with index k here.
      }
    array1[i]=(array2[1]!=""?"":"+") val (array2[num1]!=""?"":"+")    ##Assigning val to current array1 value after addition of all items in 2nd field.
    val=""                                        ##Nullifying val here.
  }
  for(o=1;o<=num;o++){                            ##Running a for loop till length of 1st array here.
    value=(value?value ",":"")array1[o]           ##Keep on appending value of array1 with index o to var value here.
  }
  $2=value                                        ##Setting value to 2nd field here.
  value=""                                        ##Nullify var value here.
}
1                                                 ##Mentioning 1 to print all lines here.
' Input_file                                      ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: That another good systematic approach. But, @sundeep pulled a rabbit out of his hat with the `match` solution. I leaned from both.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thank you sir for encouragement. Yeah Sundeep answer is 
 very Good :)

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you so much for explaining the solution in detail. While it mostly works, the one issue I see is that it does unintentional replacements in the last line. `conf_string=0,0,0,25101,0,3,1`. Which should have been `conf_string=LMN,J,IP,25101,0,3,1`

Comment: @javed, ok I have edited code as per your shown sample and tested it on mobile over https://ideone.com/x2EQ0P link too please check it once and lemme know in case of queries here.

Comment: @javed, Javed bhai, did this work for you? Lemme know in case of any queries.

Comment: Yes, it worked after your changes. Thank you so much. 
Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 2):

Using *GNU* `sed`, to wrap some shell script `$(( ))` around the sums, and then the dangerous ***`e`****val* command to run it:

```
sed 's#\(.*\)\([0-9]\++[0-9]\+\)\(.*\)#printf "\1$((\2))\3"#e' file
```

...or, with fewer backslashes `\`:

```
sed -r 's#(.*)([0-9]+\+[0-9]+)(.*)#printf "\1$((\2))\3"#e' file
```

Output of either:

```
id=6
id=10
id=251010
xyz=1+
abc=123456
conf_string=LMN,J,IP,25101,0,3,1
```

Comment: The above code assumes the input is clean and isn't full of single and double quotes -- if it were, there'd need to be additional code prepended to quote those before they could cause trouble with *`e`val*.